# Reading in multiple .rds files and creating one object

Tags: r, raster, rds

I have seen other examples of this on stackexchange but cannot seem to adapt them to my code.

Problem:
I have a folder of .rds files that I would like to read into R, then stack all the files together so I can take the mean and standard deviation. All the .rds files are 'Formal class RasterLayer' when brought into R, if that is pertinent.

**Example code:**

```
 # file path to folder where .rds files are stored
   path = "~/Predictions/"
   # create place to store files
   stack <-""
   # create vector of all .rds files in folder
   pred.dates <- dir(path, pattern =".rds")
   # loop to bring in each .rds file
   for(i in 1:length(pred.dates)){
   file <- readRDS(file.names[i],".rds")
   stack <- rbind(stack, file)
   }

   # take mean of all .rds files stacked together and plot 
   pred_mean <- mean(stack, na.rm=T)
   plot(pred_mean)

   # take sd of all .rds files stacked together and plot 
   pred_sd <- sd(stack, na.rm = T)
   plot(pred_sd)
```

However, it returns the error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'Pred_.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Seems like this should be straightforward, but perhaps I'm not using the correct function. Thanks!

Comment: where is the issue exactly ? the loop ? the mean ? what function are you referring to ? is your length returned properly?  file.names[i] does not seem to exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem with the solution by F. Privé is that they use `rbind` instead of `stack`. I would suggest doing

```
library(raster)
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "\\.rds$", full.names = TRUE)
r <- lapply(files, readRDS)
s <- stack(r)
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I can take the mean however when I try to take the sd it returns:
Error in as.double(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Code: pred_sd <- sd(s, na.rm = T)

Comment: Took an alternate route to sd and used the 'calc' function in the raster package and it works now. code:
pred_sd <- calc(s, fun = sd, na.rm = T) #take the sd

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "\\.rds$", full.names = TRUE)
stack <- do.call("rbind", lapply(files, readRDS))
```

Comment: That first line works, however the second line returns, Error: node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow, it doesn't seem like it is sourcing itself in the do.call function so I'm not sure why it is returning that error

Comment: thanks for the link, I tried calling 'Reduce" instead of 'do.call' but returns Error in rbind2(..1, r) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: Try loading **raster** with `library(raster)` and then try again.