# R: Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds (importing files)

Tags: r, import, directory, raster

I am working with the R programming language. I have a folder full of ".R" files that I want to upload into R.

The folder has the following address : C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/dk"

I tried to follow the directions from the following tutorial: [Reading in multiple .rds files and creating one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073292/reading-in-multiple-rds-files-and-creating-one-object):

```
    library(raster)

 getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents"

path = "C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/dk"

files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "\\.R$", full.names = TRUE)
r <- lapply(files, readRDS)
s <- stack(r)
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have included a screenshot which shows the general setup:

[image]

My goal is to load all these R files into R Studio at once, and then run them all at the same time - thus, creating all these functions in the global environment.

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the second answer from the question I linked was able to help!

```
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "\\.rds$", full.names = TRUE)
stack <- do.call("rbind", lapply(files, readRDS))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `source` to get the functions available in individual R files to the global environment.

```
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "\\.R$", full.names = TRUE)
lapply(files, source)
```

Comment: :Thank you for your answer! I ended up using your suggestion from the comment and used the second answer from the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68444377/r-function-has-3-objectives-but-the-control-object-assumes-1 can you please take a look at this question if you have some time? thank you so much!